# Two views one page (sorting, etc)

Tags: views

I am sure this is just by design and not much can be done, but I figured i would ask anyway...

I have a couple views on a dashboard. Each can be sorted, but when I sort one by "Date Submitted" all the others follow suit, which is expected, but not desired.

Is there a way to disconnect the Views, so that query parameters bind to a single view instead of all on screen?

Just curious,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you configure your view, if you edit the pager settings, there's a Pager ID that if you change it you'll get a different pagination for each view, you can sync some but others not and so on.

[image]

Comment: Thats awesome...I also just realized the AJAX setting does the same thing. :) Thanks!

Comment: Does this work for sorting as well?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can have exposed sorts in views, so you can control them through the url.